# how to get checked values from a checkbox-group using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to get the values of all the checked checkboxes in the checkbox-group.

```
 <div class="checkbox-group">
<div class="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-0">
<input name="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview[]" class="" id="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-0" value="physics" type="checkbox" checked="checked">physics</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-1"><input name="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview[]" class="" id="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-1" value="math" type="checkbox">math</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-2">
<input name="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview[]" class="" id="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-2" value="chemistry" type="checkbox">chemistry</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Following is script code

```
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {

        $(document).ready(function(){

        var x = $(".userform").find(":input");
        $.each(x, function(i, field){
            if(field.type == "text")
            {
                $("#results").append("name:   "+field.name + ":       " +"Value:    "+ field.value +"<br>");
            }

            else if(field.type == "checkbox")
            {
             var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

             if(result.length > 0)
                {
                $("#results").append("this is checked     "+"name:   "+field.name + ":       " +"Value:    "+ field.value +"<br>");
            }
            else{

                $("#results").append("this is unchecked");
            }
            }


        });

});


});
```

When I leave all uncheck then it gives this output

```
this is unchecked 
this is unchecked 
this is unchecked
```

but when I check any it gives this output

```
this is checked name: checkbox-group-1500619332922: Value: on
this is checked name: checkbox-group-1500619332922: Value: on
this is checked name: checkbox-group-1500619332922: Value: on
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this simple loop:

```
var values = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i,v){
  values.push($(v).val());
});
```

if you want only form a group lets say `.group` then change the selector to

```
$('.group input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

demo:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

  $('.checkbox-group').each(function() {
    var values = [];
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i, v) {
      values.push($(v).val());
    });
    console.log(values);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-0">
<input name="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview[]" class="" id="checkbox-
group-1501481486714-preview-0" value="option-1" type="checkbox" 
checked="checked">Option 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-1">
<input name="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview[]" class="" id="checkbox-
group-1501481486714-preview-1" value="option-2" type="checkbox">Option 
2</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkbox-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-0">
<input name="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview[]" class="" id="checkbox-
group-1501481486714-preview-0" value="option-1 group-2" type="checkbox" 
checked="checked">Option 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview-1">
<input name="checkbox-group-1501481486714-preview[]" class="" id="checkbox-
group-1501481486714-preview-1" value="option-2 group-2" type="checkbox">Option 
2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working. same problem when i checked one all return 'on' but when leave all uncheck then return nothing.

Comment: what do you want to return  if they are not checked?

Comment: nothing but if any one is checked want get its value i.e "phy" , "math" or "phy".

Comment: @Bashirahmad the answer should get those values in a array if the checkboxes are checked

Comment: yes i want the same but the result here is quite opposite. if i check one then loop run three times and if I check two then it run the same three times. which i think there is problem 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked' in here.

Comment: what loop runs 3 times?,see the demo

Comment: yes this works nice for single checkboxes but I am stuck because of checkbox-group. see my code.

Comment: @Bashirahmad you need to do another loop and select the checkboxes form the that group only ,see updated snippet

Comment: @Bashirahmad the code should work for you html as well, what is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150571/discussion-between-bashir-ahmad-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 0):

You can try below demo code for get selected value.

```
var demo = $("input[type="checkbox"]:checked").map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

you can try.

Comment: You can use `this.value` instead. Know your DOM Element properties.